# Discord.py real-time response to messages after going offline?

Tags: discord, discord.py

My Google-fu has failed me, Stack Overflow Gods...

I have a very basic bot running on 4 of my servers that handles scheduling and, as long as the bot is online, it works marvelously, but as soon as it goes offline for whatever reason, it stops listening to any of the messages already in the channel and will only listen to newly sent messages.

E.G. Let's say that every time the bot is online is starts a new session and when it goes offline, that session ends. So, if my bot is online for the first time, it's in Session 1 and listens to all messages sent during Session 1, but as soon as it goes offline, Session 1 ends. When it comes back online, it starts Session 2 and stops listening to messages that were sent during Session 1 and only listens to messages that are sent during Session 2.

How can I get the bot to listen to all the messages in one channel? (How can I get it to listen to all messages from all "Sessions")

Thank you kindly

Comment: You could store the message ids in a database, use [TextChannel.history](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=channel%20history#discord.TextChannel.history) to read older messages. Check if they are in your database, if not that means your bot hasn't seen them yet and you can do whatever with them. You can do this in the `on_ready` event with a limit if you'd like so it doesn't go too far back. But it is obviously not gonna respond to anything when the bot is offline. You just can't do that it doesn't make sense.

Comment: See the above. There's also the issue that discord channels can get flooded very easily - you can be forced to process hundreds or thousands of messages if you're offline for a few hours. No other bot does this; it's not worth it to try to compensate for being offline. Just try to keep your uptime as best you can.